# can we use "AND" to join past and present sentence

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

is this sentence grammatically correct ?

As a boy bill *was* afraid of dark and *has* developed a coping mechanism.

Comment: what is your purpose ? what do you want to convey ? however, to me the perfect tense sounds odd. however "and" is a coordinator conjunction correlating two similar structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work. You have written this as a sentence with "conjoint" predicates, so everything before the two predicates is assumed to have scope over both of them.

```
                was afraid of the dark
As a boy, Bill   and
                has developed a coping mechanism.
```

But that creates conflicting time references: "As a boy, Bill was afraid of the dark" implies that Bill was a boy in the past, while "As a boy, Bill has developed a coping mechanism" implies that Bill is still a boy.

There are a couple of things you could do. You might move "as a boy" to a point where it modifies only the first clause:

```
      was afraid of the dark as a boy  
 Bill  and 
      has developed a coping mechanism.
```

Or instead of conjoining predicates you could conjoin entire clauses, each with its own temporal qualifier:

```
 As a boy Bill was afraid of the dark  
  and
 Now      he has developed a coping mechanism.
```

However, all of these are odd with *and*, because the second thought doesn't really add to the first thought but contrasts with it. What's really wanted is *but* instead of *and*

> Bill was afraid of the dark as a boy, but now he's developed a coping mechanism.